# Assign session variable inside a class PHP

Tags: php, class, session-variables

I am trying to assign a session var inside a class, so I can use it in an SQL query.
I guess I am doing something wrong, as it doesn't seem to work (not assigning it).

```
class Records { 

    private $recordsTable = 'services';
    public $account;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->account = $_SESSION['account'];
        $this->conn = $db;

    }   

    public function listRecords(){
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->recordsTable." where account='".$this->account."'";
        if(!empty($_POST["search"]["value"])){
            $sqlQuery .= 'where(id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR approved LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%") ';           
        }
}
```

If I hardcode the account name in the construct like this the query works

```
$this->account = "AccountName";
```

If I echo the `$_SESSION['account']` it also prints the account

It doesn't work only if I use it like this

```
$this->account = $_SESSION['account'];
```

When I print the `$sqlQuery`, the account comes empty when I use `$this->account = $_SESSION['account'];`

So, the `$_SESSION['account']` is set correctly, and the query itself is correct too

**UPDATE:**

Strangely, even though the `$_SESSION['account']` prints the account name, if I start the session as Vishal suggested, the account start printing also inside the query

Comment: You need to call session start

Comment: `account` might not be set at all.

Comment: if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
        session_start();
       $this->account = $_SESSION['account'];
   }
Add this code in constructor

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: @draz, what do you mean? account var or account SESSION var? The session var is set as soon as the user login.

Comment: if `session_start` has been called before, the issue is within `$_SESSION['account']; `

Comment: We only know as much about your application as you tell us. Have you done any debugging? Checked if `$_SESSION['account']` contains what you expect? Have you, as people already pointed out, started the session before trying to read from or write to it? Also, how did you determine that it doesn't work? Have you echoed out the result of `$sqlQuery`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, $_SESSION['account'] is set when the user login and it is destroyed either on a timeout or user intentionally logout. So, $_SESSION['account'] is 100% populated. If I Hardcode the account name like this "$this->account = "AccountName";" the query works. I will update the post with this info.

Comment: You realize you didn't actually answer _any_ of my questions, right?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, just updated the post with it

Comment: @lStoilov create instance of Records class and echo account, Something like "echo  (new Records($db))->account" Check if it works

Comment: @Vishal, just updated the post with information pointing that your first assumption was right. Although, the session account was printing fine adding the session_start() did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if session exists if not start session below is the code snippet

```
public function __construct($db){
    if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
        session_start(); 
        $this->account = $_SESSION['account'];
    }
    $this->conn = $db;
}
```

Comment: Although an off-topic, any idea why before adding the session_start(); it was printing the account everywhere, but the query?

Comment: Where exactly you were trying to access account ? I believe there must be session_start() written on those pages as well

Comment: Well, was trying on the same file, just before the ''class Records''

Comment: Mmmm this is weird not sure what could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution** - Thanks to Vishal

Although, `$_SESSION['account']` was printing fine the account name, after adding `session_start();` it also started printing correctly inside the query too

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();
   $this->account = $_SESSION['account'];
}
```